# SQL Server 2012 Agent Job Proxy there one minute, gone the next

Tags: proxy, sql-server-2012

I had a SQL Server Agent job set up to run with a proxy account. Last night it failed to run because the run as account was cleared and now I can't see my proxy account in the run as drop down. I can still see the credentials I created and the proxy in the agent, but I can't get the proxy to show up in the drop down.

Why would that happen?